# Python Selenium browser with extensions

Tags: python, firefox, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I can't seem to find any information on how to set python to open a browser (firefox) but a version that has an extension installed such as adblock?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Instantiate `FirefoxProfile()` and use `add_extension()` to add an existing extension:

```
from selenium import webdriver

profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
profile.add_extension('path_to_extension')
profile.set_preference("extensions.adblockplus.currentVersion", "2.4")

driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=profile)
```